# JSDOM NextJS error on launch: Module not found: Can't resolve 'net'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jsdom

Need Help

I was building my first big NextJS project with News API and wanted to use **jsdom** to scrape the news URL, but when I import this dependency into my project I get the `Module not found: Can't resolve 'net'` error.

```
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
```

```
import Image from "next/image";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function MinBlock({ headline, tagline, imgUrl }) {
  const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
  const { Readability } = require("@mozilla/readability");

  function urlPasser(str) {
    const regExp = /^http/gi;
    if (regExp.test(str)) {
      return str;
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }

  return (
    <a href="#" className="grid grid-cols-4 gap-2 group">
      <div
        className="col-span-1 bg-cover h-24 relative"
        // style={{ backgroundImage: `url('${imgUrl}')` }}
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6 ))`,
        }}
      >
        {urlPasser(imgUrl) && (
          <Image
            src={imgUrl}
            alt=""
            srcset=""
            fill
            style={{
              objectFit: "cover",
            }}
          />
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="col-span-3">
        <p className="font-light text-xs">{tagline}</p>
        <h3 className="font-header text-xl my-2 group-hover:text-primary-600">
          {headline}
        </h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  );
}

export default MinBlock;
```

Answer (score 0):

require the jsdom inside of get static or serverside props, because it needs to run with node.js